# Java Mail Body Part getFileName can't read application/octet-stream data

Tags: jakarta-mail, decoding

I am trying to read an attachments' filename through the BodyPart class. I am calling the BodyPart getFileName method.

For any content type "application/octet-stream" I get the incorrect filename like below:

> =?Windows-1252?Q?(07)_HQ14_MAtv_Qu=E9bec_Grille_HIVER_2014_Semaine_du_17_?= =?Windows-1252?Q?f=E9vrier_v1.xlsx?=

when it should read something like this:

> (08) HQ14 MAtv Québec Grille HIVER 2014 Semaine du 24 février v1.xlsx

Is there any utility that will successfully decode the octet-stream to a readable output?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this. There is actually a utility method that will solve this.

If you pass in the filename string to MimeUtility.decode method it will return the string with the correct filename. Please see for more information:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText

For example:

String realFileName = MimeUtility.decode("=?Windows-1252?Q?(07)_HQ14_MAtv_Qu=E9bec_Grille_HIVER_2014_Semaine_du_17_?= =?Windows-1252?Q?f=E9vrier_v1.xlsx?=") will return "(07) HQ14 MAtv Québec Grille HIVER 2014 Semaine du 17 février v1.xlsx".